# What version of python can I use with Twisted/Zope?

Tags: python, twisted, zope

I noticed that Twisted has a dependency on Zope. I found that when I tried to install Zope, after running, ./configure it tells me I need to use python2.4 (not python 2.5+ which I would like to be using).

However, I have seen some tutorials and guides that suggested using python 2.5 for Twisted. So I'm just generally confused. Has anyone set this up and ran some of the twsited web examples that use zope? What version of python did you use? Was there an installation guide you followed somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

Twisted doesn't have a dependency on full `zope`. It's just [`zope.interface`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface), which is a small pure-python module packaged separately from all zope.

You can download the `.tar.gz` version and run the usual `python setup.py install`, that should work. Or if your operational system includes a package management system, you could check it for a easy-to-install package. Example, in debian/ubuntu you could do:

```
apt-get install python-zopeinterface
```

or even

```
apt-get install python-twisted
```

directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you install twisted with `pip install` or `easy_install` it will download and install zope.install for you as well.